# How to find VM OS installation media file in the Proxmox Web Interface?

Tags: virtualization

I have installed Proxmox and wanted to create a VM by using the Proxmox web interface GUI (now the version is *2.0-38/af81df02*)

However I have problem to **find my Guest VM OS installation CD/DVD ISO file** in the web GUI interface.

[image]

There is no ISO file can be found even I am very very sure I have copied the Ubuntu ISO file into the `/home/ISOs` directory which I have created in the "storage" tab.

[image]

[image]

Why I cannot find the "Installation Media File" in Proxmox after I have copied it to the correct local directory and created the correct path in the Proxmox "storage" tab?

Comment: I have found the solution: You can upload you ISO files to **/var/lib/vz/template/iso** directory on  Proxmox  server. Then when you choose the default storage "local" you will see your iso files. The solution details are found at [link](http://blog.gambliser.com/2012/02/how-to-create-a-new-virtual-machine-on-promox-system/)

Answer (score 26):

You'll have to place the ISO in the `/var/lib/vz/template/iso` folder for it to be recognized by Proxmox.

To break it down:

- Backups   - `/var/lib/vz/dump`
- ISOs      - `/var/lib/vz/template/iso`
- Images    - `/var/lib/vz/images`
- Templates - `/var/lib/vz/template/cache`

Cheers!

Answer (score 8):

You can upload ISOs via the web interface by selecting a storage (e.g. `local`) in the tree, then selecting the `Content` tab and then clicking the `Upload` button. The dialog which pops up allows you to upload ISOs which are then available in the storage when creating VMs.

Comment: Great tip, just what I was looking for! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
/var/lib/pve/local-btrfs/template/iso
```

что-бы проверить файлы можно следующей командой

```
du -h | sort -h
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please translate your answer to English, since this is the designated language of communication here.